# Manual WCF Service Design

Tags: wcf, manual

[image: This is my Solution Structure of Service & Domain Layer]

First please tell me is this solution structure is good as far as Architecture is concern?
I have XXXX. Business project in center.
XXXX. Contract project has a reference of it.
XXXX. Service project has reference of Contract and Business project.

Now i want my service to be hosted on flexible environments. That's why I want to put custom hosting logic in the Service > Host folder. This project will also have Custom Instance providing facility so that My service classes can be created with some parametric constructor.
Also I need to have different kind of endpoints so I also have a folder for Bindings

These 3 custom things currently suffice my requirement.

Now please guide me with some sample code snippet for Bindings/Host/Instance

Answer (score 1):

I do not know what you mean by

> i want my service to be hosted on flexible environments

and

> I want to put custom hosting logic in the Service > Host folder

The type of hosting container used depends on the type of project (web, console, windows service, etc) which the service implementation is reference in. This is not something you want to bundle into one project, you should have a different project (or even a different solution) for each of your different service instances.

And this leads to your general solution structure. By placing the contracts as a project in your solution, you are coupling the contract assembly build (and potentially, deployment) to the build and deployment of your solution. The contracts should ideally be in their own solution so that they can be built and managed separately from your service implementation. What if at some time you need to maintain multiple versions of your contracts?

I think your approach to create a generic service which can be anything to anyone is way to complex. You should let WCF take care of this kind of work for you, create a different project at least for each of your service implementations, and defer the bindings management  to deploy-time.

Additionally, unless you are writing your own custom bindings code you will not require a folder for bindings.

Bindings can (and should) be defined in configuration when you ship your endpoint, and to some extent, the decision about which transport binding to use should be an administration or management rather than a development concern.

Comment: The 2 lines what you didn't get means, I want to build a hosting framework which will have minimum configurations, and capable to provide an environment to actual hosting environment. That can be Console/self hosting, or Window Service or IIS/WAS.

Now can you tell me what can be ideal solution structure for business domain prject, contract project and service implementation project for my case. Should 3 to be placed in 3 different solution??

Comment: My point was why are you building a hosting framework when WCF provides this for you? You can provide minimal configurations by understanding what your requirements are up front and building out the configuration when you deploy the service.